# Is there any difference between object of ordinary class and object of generic type class?

Tags: java

Is there any difference between object of class `MyClass` and object of class `MyClass<String>` apart from the fact that one is of 'Raw Type' and other is of 'Generic type'.If we call 'getClass()' method on object of Raw type 'MyClass' and on object of Generic Type `MyClass<String>` both will return same answer. So what exactly the difference is ?. Thanks

```
class MyClass
{

}


class MyClass<String>
{

}
```

Comment: Read this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The first is *raw*, the other is generic

Comment: You can't define both classes with the same fully-qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

Generics  provides compile time type-safety and ensures that you only insert correct Type in collection and avoids ClassCastException in runtime.

Now for example to show you simple advantage I have provided this code

```
public class Box<T> {

  private T t;

  public void add(T t) {
    this.t = t;
  }

  public T get() {
    return t;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
     Box<String> stringBox = new Box<String>();

     integerBox.add(new Integer(10));
     stringBox.add(new String("Hello World"));

     System.out.printf("Integer Value :%d\n\n", integerBox.get());//10
     System.out.printf("String Value :%s\n", stringBox.get());//Hello World
  }
}
```

For more detail you can check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html)